# Convert rows into json object in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-13

With PostgreSQL 13 I'm trying to convert rows with 2 columns into a JSON object where a column value is the key and the other column is the value.
My table:

```
key      | value  
-------- | -------- 
key1     | value1           
key2     | value2        
key3     | value3
```

My expected result:
`{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}`

I found the json_object function on postgresql website : [PostgreSQL JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) but I can't get it to work.

I tried with other functions:

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(key ,value))
FROM mytable
```

but it gives me an array of json objects
`[{"key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value2"},{"key3":"value3"}]`

I know I can still build it with string functions but I feel like it's an easy task even if I can't get it :-/

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_object_agg()`

```
select jsonb_object_agg(key, value)
from the_table
```